# Cannot read property 'id' of undefined because data is not fetched yet

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I load my App, The data from firebase is fetched in `componentdidmount`. I'm currently passing `postComments={comments}` as a prop. However before this happens my app crashes with

> Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

on line

```
const comments = this.props.comments[post.id] || [];
```

this is because, my posts have not been fetched yet. How can I prevent this crash from happening before `componentdidmount` is activated

```
import React from 'react';
import Photo from './photo';
import Comments from './Comments'
class Single extends React.Component {

  render() {
    console.log(this.props)
    const {posts, match} = this.props; 
    const i = this.props.posts.findIndex((post) => post.id === match.params.id);
    const post = this.props.posts[i];

    const comments = this.props.comments[post.id] || [];

        return (
          <div className="single-photo">
          <Photo key={i} post={post} i={i} {...this.props} />  
          <Comments {...this.props} postComments={comments} />   
          </div>
        )
      }
};

export default Single;
```

Comment: Why not instantiate the component empty and then populate it by modifying its state once the fetch is complete?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add this test:

```
const comments = (post && this.props.comments[post.id]) || [];
```

Comment: I still get the same crash Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Comment: the problem is post is undefined and it causes a crash when i try and retrieve it from the object

Comment: That's why i added the test, but i see you should better handle fetching the data apart and setting a parameter in the state like :{ loading: true }, and render your app just in case this.state.loading is equal to false and make sure you've got some data.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty ways to handle this but I would just add:

```
const comments = this.props.comments[post.id] === undefined ? [] : this.props.comments[post.id]
```